# export Hive table data in csv file of s3 bucket

Tags: hive, amazon-emr

I'm trying to export data of Hive Table *f1* into a csv file of `s3://mubucket/exported.csv`. I've created a cluster in Amazon EMR and using `emr-4.0.0`. Hadoop distribution:`Amazon 2.6.0` and `Hive 1.0.0`. What will be the query to export data from Hive table to csv file of s3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

The traditional method is to use `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` to define an output location in Amazon S3, then insert data into the table. This results in CSV files being stored in the Amazon S3 bucket.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mydata (foo STRING, bar INT, ...)
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mydata
SELECT * FROM existing_table;
```

Comment: Thanks for ur replay. Will try this.